# Cakephp find order by an associated model

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, left-join, cakephp-2.3

After spending few hours to find a solution for the following issue I´m hoping you can help me.

I have two tables:

```
Event hasmany Appointments and Appointment belongsto Event
```

Now I perform in my `EventsController`:

```
$this->Event->find('all')
```

Now I want to order the Events by Appointments. So that the Event with the earliest Appointment is first in the array and so on. I´ve tried many ways, with Containable, Joins, Grouping, Subselects but nothing works.

To perform the find('all') on `$this->Event->Appointment` is not a solution due to the fact that I want every Event just ones.

Edit #1:
My only solution so far was 
    $events = $this->Event->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => '(SELECT event_id, MIN(start) start FROM appointments GROUP BY event_id)',
                'alias' => 'Appointment',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Event.id = Appointment.event_id'
                    )
                )
            ),
        'order' => array(
            'Appointment.start ASC'
            )
        ));

But this is not the best solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to create a virtual field representing the earliest appointment date that you can sort by

Put this in your Event model:

```
function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    $this->virtualFields['firstappt'] = 'SELECT MIN(Appointment.created) FROM appointments AS Appointment WHERE Appointment.event_id = Event.id';
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

You should be able to use this code in your controller:

```
$this->Event->find('all',array('order' => array('firstappt')));
```